# Recargar el listado después de insertar un registro usando PHP, MySQL y JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

he creado un formulario de cargar de productos usando  PHP,
MySQL y  javascript, En la misma página tengo el listado de lo cargado,cuando  agrego un producto o si quiero borrar un producto lo hace,  pero no me actualiza la tabla del listado. Como hago para que al cargar el producto me actualice en listado automáticamente.

Aqui les dejo una URL donde se puede ver el problema: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.flatzi.com/test/consulta.html)

Voy a repetir el fragmento de la pregunta porque me pide escribir más detalles :) 
Hola a todos, he creado un formulario de cargar de productos usando  PHP,
MySQL y  javascript, En la misma página tengo el listado de lo cargado,cuando  agrego un producto o si quiero borrar un producto lo hace,  pero no me actualiza la tabla del listado.

```js
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
var listado = document.getElementById('listado');
// Listar productos cargados
function listar() {
    fetch('listado.php')
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(data => {
            var datos = JSON.stringify(data);
            for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
                var Id = data[i]['id'];
                var Nombre = data[i]['nombre'];
                var Precio = data[i]['precio'];
                var Codigo = data[i]['codigo'];
                var Imagen = data[i]['imagen'];
                if (Imagen == null) {
                    Imagen = 'sinfoto.png'
                }
                listado.innerHTML += `
                <tr >
                    <th scope="row">${Id}</th>
                        <td><img width=35" src="img/producto/${Imagen}" > </th>
                        <td>${Nombre}</td>
                        <td>${Precio}</td>
                        <td>${Codigo}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="editar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                <span class="material-icons"> edit </span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="${Id}" onClick="borrar(this.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                <span class="material-icons"> delete </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `;
            }
        });
}
listar();


// Cargar registros de producto
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = new FormData(form);
    fetch('guardar.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: datos
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data === 'error') {
                resultado.innerHTML = `
                <div class="alert alert-danger my-2" role="alert">
                    ¡Llena todo los campos!
                </div>`
            } else {
                resultado.innerHTML = `
                <div class="alert alert-primary my-2" role="alert">
                ${data} 
                </div>`;
                form.reset();
            }

        });
});
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <form id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre del Producto" name="nombre" class="form-control my-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Precio" name="precio" class="form-control my-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Codigo" name="codigo" class="form-control my-2">
            <input type="file" placeholder="Cargar imagen" name="imagen" class="form-control my-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar">Guardar</button>
        </form>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Imagen</th> 
              <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
              <th scope="col">Preico</th>
              <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
              <th scope="col">Accion</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="listado">
        </table>
    </div>
<script src="funciones.js"></script>
```

Código PHP:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    include('conectar.php');
    if($_POST['nombre'] == '' ||  $_POST['precio'] =="" || $_POST['codigo'] ==""){
        echo json_encode ("error");
    }else{
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $precio = $_POST['precio'];
        $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
        if (empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])) {
            $imagen = '';
        }else{
            $prefijo = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,6);
            $imagen =  $prefijo."-".$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
        }
        //CARGAR IMAGEN
        if ($imagen != "") {
            $destino =  "img/producto/".$imagen;
            copy($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$destino); 
           }else{
                $imagen = 'sinfoto.jpg';
        }
        //Insertar en la db
        $sql = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_producto (nombre, precio, codigo, imagen) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
        $sql->bindParam(1, $nombre);
        $sql->bindParam(2, $precio);
        $sql->bindParam(3, $codigo);
        $sql->bindParam(4, $imagen);
            if($sql->execute()){
                echo json_encode ("Datos almacenados");
                }else{
                echo json_encode ("error");
            }
       }
```

Comment: ¿De que manera obtienes los datos la primera vez?

Comment: Lo obtengo con javascript
fetch('listado.php')
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(data => {}

Comment: Coloca ese script dentro de una función, a dicha función mandala llamar cuando cargues el sitio y tambien cuando sea exitoso el fetch del post para guardar.

Comment: ¿Te devuelve lo mismo un `listado.php` que una llamada a `guardar.php`? Es decir, ¿en `guardar.php` devuelves un listado como haces en el otro PHP? Tal y como tienes el código es lo que debería hacer.

Comment: Si, el devuelve lo mismo, si tengo 3 registros cargado y cargo uno más me muestra siempre los tres registros, debo refrescar para que me muestre el registro cargado.

Les dejo un enlace para que vean: https://www.flatzi.com/test/consulta.html 

Y el código aquí: https://github.com/Armoa/crub2020.

Y gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @EdgardoArmoa, edita la pregunta y agrega el código PHP donde insertas el nuevo registro y cómo devuelves los datos.

Comment: Ahora he actualizado con el PHP que inserta el registro

Comment: El listado.php es este:
 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 include('conectar.php');
 $sql = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_producto ORDER BY id DESC' );
 $sql->execute();

 $Producto = array();
 while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $Producto[] = $row;
 }
echo json_encode($Producto)."\n";

Comment: Hola gente, alguien puede ayudarme con mi código? No logro que recargue el listado después de agregar un ítem a la lista. Hice lo que Jonathan  Orta  me sugirió pero igual no recarga